# How can I block a THREE.js raycast with HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I would like HTML elements on my page to block THREE.js raycasts, how can I do this?
The problem I'm having is the raycast retrieves objects in my scene when the user clicks on an open DIV element (It retrieves the objects behind the DIV). I don't want to disable raycasting whilst the DIV is open, I purely want the DIV to block the raycast.

Thanks,
Reece

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is probably to use the DOM event-handling.

Suppose you have a dom-structure like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <canvas class="threejs-canvas"></canvas>
  <div class="some-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

And you want interactions in `.some-overlay` to not have an effect on the three.js scene in the canvas-element, you need to do two things:

1. the raycaster should use only events that happen on the `.container`-element
2. clicks within the overlay need to use `stopPropagation()` to stop events from bubbling up to the container

So, together this could be something like this:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var overlay = document.querySelector('.some-overlay');

container.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // do raycasting here
});

overlay.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation(); // prevent event from bubbling up to .container

  // ...do whatever you like
});
```

It gets even easier, if you listen for the events for the raycaster on the canvas-element itself. In that case, the events won't ever reach the canvas-element and there is nothing special you need to do.

Comment: if going for div, care in which phase you are stopping the propagation, bubbling or capturing phase. in complex applications this is very crucial and i had a lot of headaches about this, especially in ios safari.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I recommend Martins answer. This is how I'd do it, because you have more control on which events you pass through.
Jut to have another solution, you could probably try it with css and 2 divs only.

```
div.overlay{
   pointer-events:none
}


<canvas>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="overlayChild">
    <a>CLICK</a>
  </div>
</div>
```